# Can not find required columns: sku

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, import, csv

I'm trying a .csv import with the normal import function of Magento (not the dataflow). I first exported all the products from my store and used that sheet as a template for mine.

When I try to import the sheet I get the following error: `Can not find required columns: sku`

I'm using Excel as my editor and I tried saving it as a `MSDOS CSV` but that didn't work either.

Note I opened the .csv in a text editor and the seperator was a `;` I know the default seperator is a `,` but how would that work with defining the categories?

Also the `SKU` is present in the file

Comment: what fields did you import? for example `sku, name, id`?

Comment: Save the file in normal CSV mode (not msdos csv mode)

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I've used the export sheet with all the store attributes

Comment: Delete any empty `sku` fields if you have. Or else I would do `import/data-flow profile` by adding each fields cumulatively.

Comment: You have to declare that you are using `;` in stead of the default `,`, you will go to System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles > Import All Products > Data Format > Value Delimiter and change this value to `;`.